# How do I identify this ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

Previous owners didn't leave a remote, so I need to get a replacement. Should be easy enough. But no brand or model name is visible. How do I identify this?

I bought a Hampton Bay replacement remote from Amazon and tried all 16 combinations for 4 dip switches, then borrowed a Concord brand remote from a neighbor and tried all 32 combinations for 5 dip switches, both to no avail. Getting desperate at this point since a recent power outage somehow left it stuck on at high speed. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thank you!

[image: ceiling fan from below]
[image: ceiling fan from side]

Comment: 16 dip switches so you tried all 65536 combinations? Assuming only on/off...

Comment: @SolarMike I tried all 16 combinations for the remote that had 4 dip switches and all 32 combinations for the remote that had 5 dip switches. Edited to clarify, thanks.

Comment: I’d try Big Ass Fans. Great service and can recommend controllers too. https://www.bigassfans.com/

Comment: Have you tried removing some of the covers on the fan to see if there is a model number plate inside?

Comment: Yeah, this fan should have a nameplate *somewhere* on it....

Comment: Are you _sure_ the fan is not controlled by a switch somewhere?  It would be kind of odd to have a light or a fan in that location that didn't have a switch going to it.

Comment: @MartinBonner &ThreePhaseEel I agree there must be an identification plate somewhere. I will try harder to find it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Curiously, the previous owners did claim that a particular switch controls it. But when I flip that switch, all I get is that another lamp in the neighboring room flickers wildly. I have no idea what that means and have been assuming it's unrelated, but if that sounds like a lead to you, I'd be happy to follow it further...

Comment: A lamp flickering wildly is a concern wether it's related or not.  Flickering could mean arcing, and arcing can lead to fires.  It might not be _that_ dangerous, but not something I would let go.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That only happens when I hold down one of the push buttons of the switch I was talking about. As far as I know, that switch is basically useless. Just added in that information since it is the one that the previous owners pointed me to.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Agree it needs to be investigated, but I suspect more likely that the fan is jammed/broken in some way, and the rush of current to it is inducing enough current in the lighting circuit to cause LED lights to flicker.